# Applied patch SUPEE-6788: nothing changed

Tags: patches

I have Magento 1.9.1.0 and have applied all patches till this last one.
Today I've modified a few files and done a `git commit`, then I've downloaded SUPEE-6788 and applied it.

AFter applying the patch I've done a `git status` and... no files were affected a part from `app/config` of course!

Ive' opened the patch file and checked some of the file affected:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
```

They don't even exist in my Magento installation. Is this normal or am I missing something Biiiiiiig??

My Magento installation seem to work normally..

Thanks

Comment: If the files don't exist in your magento installation and you apply the patch, it should give you an error. As you don't write about any kind of error, I'd say this is a strong sign that things just got mixed up. IIRC there is a mis-documentation for applying patches that suggest to use the `/bin/sh` command to run the patch files, but the files are written in bash, so you have to use the `/bin/bash` command to execute it. But that's only a short notice, you should provide the command you applied and it's output (and exist status) with your question so it's more clear what you're asking about.

Comment: Could you please check and update your question which version/file of the patch you downloaded and applied?

Comment: The patch obviously did not apply successfully. Please show the whole output that you got when applying the patch. If it fails at any file, nothing will change.

Comment: Ok.. thanks. Upon looking at the output i can see an error `Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file .htaccess
Hunk #1 FAILED at 207.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.rej
patching file .htaccess.sample
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php ....` then it goes on

Comment: I use `nginx` so I don't use the `.htaccess` file, but it's present

Answer (score 0):

I've solved following other advices.. 
I've downloaded a copy of Magento 1.9.1.0, extracted the `.htaccess` file and copied it over my magento installation. I don't use Apache so I didn't even bother saving the old .htaccess file (besides, it's on git).
The patch applied successfully and in GIT many files appear changed.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted if it solves your problem.